# Understanding exec command

Tags: bash, shell

Looking for some basic help in shell programming.

Suppose we have a command known as `foobar`, then what is the effect of shell invocation

1. `exec foobar`
2. `exec 2> /var/log/foobar.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first [`exec`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) command should only be used in a script — not at a command line terminal.  It replaces the shell with the program `foobar`, instead of running it as a separate child process.  Any commands in the script after the `exec foobar` will not be executed (even if the shell fails to find `foobar` to execute); if it is an interactive terminal session, it will report the error and continue.

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`
>
> If *command* is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process. If the `-l` option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to command. This is what the login program does. The `-c` option causes command to be executed with an empty environment. If `-a` is supplied, the shell passes name as the zeroth argument to command. If command cannot be executed for some reason, a non-interactive shell exits, unless the *execfail* shell option is enabled. In that case, it returns failure. An interactive shell returns failure if the file cannot be executed.

The second `exec` (with I/O redirection but no command) changes things so that the standard error stream goes to the file `/var/log/foobar.log`.  Any further error messages from the shell, or from commands executed by the shell, go to the log file (unless there's another lot of I/O redirection).

> If no command is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment. If there are no redirection errors, the return status is zero; otherwise the return status is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec foobar
```

will replace your shell process with `foobar`. I do not think you mean `exec 2>/var/log/foobar.log` but rather `exec foobar 2>/var/log/foobar.log`. This will do the same with sending 2 i.e. standard error messages to specified log file. You can read man page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html).

`exec(1)` command is similar to `exec(3)` call. It replaces the code segment of calling process from that of called program. 1 and 3 signify man page sections.

Comment: `exec 2>/var/log/foobar.log` has a specific and useful meaning.